Cannot get RSS feed using tidyRSS
I have been using the following R code in RStudio for several months and it worked well without a need for while loop, just at the first run.
It takes RSS feed from EDGAR.
feed_url = c("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=4&company=&dateb=&owner=only&start=0&count=10&output=atom")

feed_test_222 <- NULL
attempt <- 0
while( is.null(feed_test_222) && attempt <= 14) {
  attempt <- attempt + 1
  cat("attempt: ", attempt," ")
  try(
    feed_test_222 <- as.data.frame(tidyfeed(feed_url))
  )
 }

However, in recent few weeks, I had to repeat the call more and more times to get parsing (while loop). Otherwise, I have been getting the error as shown below, now even after 15 attempts.
attempt:  15   Error in safe_get(feed, config = ua): Attempt to get feed was unsuccessful (non-200 response). Feed may not be available.  

I really do not know what to try because there was no change in the method, functions, and it was getting progressively worse to the point of failure after 15 attempts.
In set_user function ua <- user_agent("tidyRSS/2.0.4")
No improvement after restarting R, Rstudio, reloading tidyRSS.
I will appreciate any advice on what may be happening and how to fix it.

hi there, welcome. Do you know which error code you're getting? There's a possibility it could be a 403 code (i.e. they are blocking you)

have you considered using their API? https://www.sec.gov/search-filings/edgar-application-programming-interfaces

library(httr); GET(feed_url, verbose()) returns 403 with a following content - https://gistpreview.github.io/?bf86d1b5c91a02b3f011fd1c5d3e5176

Thanks Mark and margusl. There is indeed 403 error which was not shown by tidyfeed. In the past, I used another EDGAR program which warned me about this overuse but I changed the code and it was OK. I will follow up with EDGAR to fix the problem, perhaps accomodating their API. Great thanks again.
